# onClickListener в RecyclerView срабатывает не каждый раз

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Столкнулся со странной ситуацией: есть `recyclerView` состоящий из `cardview` в котором в свою очередь текстовые поля и FloatingActionButton. Пытаюсь навесить в адаптере слушатель onClickListener на этот самый Fab. Проблема в том что он срабатывает, но не с первого раза, а раза с пятого, и то при условии если быстро кликать по ней. Проблема не в компоненте. Тоже самое пробовал и с обычной кнопкой. Вот код адаптера. Разметку думаю смысла не имеет прилагать.

```
public class MyEventsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyEventsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Event> events;
    private Context context;

    public MyEventsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> dataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.events = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyEventsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                             int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_event_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyEventsListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final Event event = events.get(position);

        viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(event.getTitle());
        viewHolder.eventPlace.setText(event.getPlace());
        viewHolder.eventStartDate.setText(context.getString(R.string.stars_at) + " " + event.getStartDate());
        viewHolder.eventDescription.setText(event.getDescription());
        viewHolder.eventCategories.setText(event.getCategories());
        viewHolder.eventMembers.setText(String.valueOf(event.getMembers()));
        if (event.getHashTags().length() == 0)
            viewHolder.eventHashTags.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            viewHolder.eventHashTags.setText(event.getHashTags());

        viewHolder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, event.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Вот тут не с первого раза клик срабатывает
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return events.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView eventTitle;
        TextView eventPlace;
        TextView eventStartDate;
        TextView eventDescription;
        TextView eventCategories;
        TextView eventMembers;
        TextView eventHashTags;
        FloatingActionButton editButton;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            eventTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventTitle);
            eventPlace = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventPlace);
            eventStartDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventStartDate);
            eventDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventDescription);
            eventCategories = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventCategories);
            eventMembers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventMembers);
            eventHashTags = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventHashTags);
            editButton = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        }
    }

}
```

Разметка итема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_main_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/eventInfoLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/main_dark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventPlace"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/main_dark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventStartDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventPlace"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/main_dark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventStartDate"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventHashTags"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventDescription"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_hash_tags"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventCategoriesTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventHashTags"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/categories"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventCategories"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eventCategoriesTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eventCategoriesTitle"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/membersTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventCategoriesTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/members"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventMembers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/membersTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/membersTitle"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/editButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventDescription"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/yellow_dark"
                app:elevation="0dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: В адаптере не видать ошибок... Приведите, всё же, разметку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: Не факт, что в этом дело, но верхний линеар кажется лишним. Второй линеар точно лишний и верхний из двух Relative - тоже. Вроде как не хорошо слишком большую вложенность элементов делать. Попробуйте, для начала, убрать всё лишнее.

Comment: Согласен, убрал все лишнее. Копипастил просто=) Но! Все равно такая же проблема. Разметку обновил

Comment: Никаких ```OnItemTouchListener``` не добавляли к ```RecyclerView```? Добавьте код где настраиваете список и адаптер. Скорее всего кто-то где-то раньше перехватывает событие.

Comment: Хм... Всё ещё не видать никаких ошибок... Может вы где-то какой-нибудь onTouch recycler-у присвоили и он конфликтует? Ещё, может, TextView из разметки перекрывают FAB - проверьте это убрав всё, кроме FAB из разметки.

Comment: Да, и верхний линеар всё ещё кажется лишним)

Comment: Господа, спасибо большое. Глаз замылился наверно.. Да, onItemTouch всю малину портил оказывается. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я набросал ответ, если есть чем дополнить для вашего случая - отредактируйте)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Хорошо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобное поведение может быть вызвано конфлитком с другими слушателями прикосновений, присвоенными вне адаптера, напрямую для `RecyclerView`. Надо искать в коде `RecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(...)` и убирать его.