# Отклик на касание по cardview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть список кликабельных `CardView` построенных с помощью `RecyclerView` и кастомного `Адаптера` со стандартной реализацией. `ViewHolder` имплементирует `OnClickListener`. Отсутствует анимация "касания" элемента. Т.е. при нажатии на любое `cardView` нет никакого отклика, что нажатие действительно произошло, срабатывает только лишь один `OnClickListener`.

Как можно прикрутить анимацию `ripple` эффекта? Вероятно есть уже готовые реализации от самого гугла, но найти ничего не получается почему-то, кроме [такого](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/animations.html). 
Попробовал сделать, анимация действительно появилась, но теперь не работает метод `OnClickListener` :) Вернее, работает, но только если нажимать на края `cardview` (видимо там где у меня определен `layout_margin` и куда анимация нажатия не достает). Как можно решить проблему? Спасибо

разметка cardview.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_margin"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
<!-- тут много textView и LinearLayout -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Задавал как-то похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472834/onclicklistener-%D0%B2-recyclerview-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Comment: @АндроидАндроид спасибо, проверил, у меня `onTouchListener` нигде не переопределен) Думал его использовать, чтобы как раз создать анимацию нажатия, но решил сначала спросить тут о целесообразонсти

Comment: сложно судить о том, что сделано у вас по ссылке на туториал. Выкладывайте свой код.

Comment: @metalurgus выложил же разметку. В документации сказано использовать для фона 

"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
так я и сделал в разметке `cardview.xml`

Comment: Вообще для анимации нажатия надо делать отдельные xml-файлы для тех вьюх, которые будут анимироваться при нажатии

Comment: @АндроидАндроид понятное дело, но думаю это больше верно для кастомной анимации. В рассматриваемом контексте, уже все придумано за нас и тем более включено в стандартную реализацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо это особенности разработки под Android, которые нужно просто знать.

Убрал из  разметки `android:clickable="true"` и все заработало как нужно.
Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет в будущем.

Comment: Не пойму, вроде все сделал так же, но у меня почему то не реагирует...

Comment: Ага это мой слушатель виноват...